# Guess the functional form of a graph

Tags: statistics, functions, optimization, graphing-functions, regression

Can you guess the functional form of the following curve

[image: y vs x]

y is 0 at x= Infinite ; y is very small ( +ve near to zero) at x=0

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many functions that fit your criteria, but it does look like Planck's Distribution. Which is of form:

$$f(x)=\frac{Ax^3}{e^{Bx}-1}$$
$x\in \mathbb R $ and  $A$, $B$ constants

Look at [this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2825500x%5E3%29%2F%28e%5E%280.1x%29-1%29+0+to+100)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that this much information doesn't specify the curve completely: there are several that will fit this definition and overall shape. One option is

$$\frac{2abx}{x^2+b^2}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are numbers that you can pick: $a$ will be the maximum height, and $b$ will be the $x$-value that it happens at.

One that decays a lot faster is

$$\frac ab xe^{1-\frac xb}$$

where $(a,b)$ is again the position of the top of the bump.